# php/jQuery - formvalidation, get value of dynamically added inputs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, formvalidation.io

I am trying to use the [Formvalidation.io plugin](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/), to dynamically add input fields.

These are my inputs:

```
<div class="col-lg-4">

    <label class="control-label">Model</label>
    <select name="box[0].model" class="ui dropdown dropdown-model semantic-dropdown">
        <option value="">Choose Model</option>
        <option value="model_one">Model One</option>
        <option value="model_two">Model Two</option>
        <option value="model_three">Model Three</option>
    </select>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label class="control-label">Type</label>
    <select name="box[0].type" class="ui dropdown dropdown-type semantic-dropdown">
        <option value="">Choose Type</option>
        <option value="0">Ingen Konfiguration</option>
        <option value="1">Sommer</option>
        <option value="2">Vinter</option>
    </select>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <label class="control-label">Temperatur</label>

    <select name="box[0].temperatur" class="ui dropdown dropdown-temperatur semantic-dropdown">
        <option value="">Choose Temperatur</option>
        <option value="0">No Temperature</option>
        <option value="1">2-8 Grader</option>
        <option value="2">15-25 Grader</option>
        <option value="3">Frozen</option>
    </select>

</div>
<a href="#" class="addButton">Add extra input</a>
```

And, my template for the hidden fields:

```
<!-- The template for adding new field -->
<div class="form-group hide" id="bookTemplate">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <select name="model" class="ui dropdown dropdown-model semantic-dropdown">
            <option value="">Choose Model</option>
            <option value="model_one">Model One</option>
            <option value="model_two">Model Two</option>
            <option value="model_three">Model Three</option>

        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <select name="type" class="ui dropdown dropdown-type semantic-dropdown">
            <option value="">Choose Type</option>
            <option value="0">Ingen Konfiguration</option>
            <option value="1">Sommer</option>
            <option value="2">Vinter</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">

        <select name="temperatur" class="ui dropdown dropdown-temperatur semantic-dropdown">
            <option value="">Vælg Temperatur</option>
            <option value="0">No Temperature</option>
            <option value="1">2-8 Grader</option>
            <option value="2">15-25 Grader</option>
            <option value="3">Frozen</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END HIDDEN TEMPLATE-->
```

Adding the fields and validating them dynamically works like it should. However, I am not seeing the values of the inputs, when the form is submitted: This is the `var_dump($_POST)` of above:

```
"array(4) {
  ["box"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["model"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["type"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["temperatur"]=>
  string(0) ""
```

The form is submitted using AJAX:

```
//Submit the form:
$('#bookingform').on('submit', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form from submitting
    $form = $(this);
    // Use Ajax to submit form data
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/submit-form',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data.result);
            if (data.result == 'success') {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                alert('Error #1');
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("ERROR");

        }
    });

});
```

Running a `console.log($form.serialize());` on the form:

```
box%5B0%5D.model=model_one&box%5B0%5D.type=1&box%5B0%5D.temperatur=1&model=&type=&temperatur=
```

As you can see, I not getting the values of the `box[o].name` - furthermore, I am not interested in the input values of the hidden fields, only if they are visible (`box[].name`)

**EDIT:**
 Below is the javascript code for adding the inputs:

```
bookIndex = 0;
.. code here that is not relevant ..          
// Add button click handler
          .on('click', '.addButton', function() {
              bookIndex++;
              var $template = $('#bookTemplate'),
                  $clone = $template
                  .clone()
                  .removeClass('hide')
                  .removeAttr('id')
                  .attr('data-book-index', bookIndex)
                  .insertBefore($template);

              // Update the name attributes
              $clone
                  .find('[name="model"]').attr('name', 'box[' + bookIndex + '].model').end()
                  .find('[name="type"]').attr('name', 'box[' + bookIndex + '].type').end()
                  .find('[name="temperatur"]').attr('name', 'box[' + bookIndex + '].temperatur').end();

              //Semantic Dropdown - refresh dynamic added dropdowns:
              $('.semantic-dropdown').dropdown();

              // Add new fields
              // Note that we also pass the validator rules for new field as the third parameter
              $('#bookingform')
                  .formValidation('addField', 'box[' + bookIndex + '].model', titleValidators)
                  .formValidation('addField', 'box[' + bookIndex + '].type', isbnValidators)
                  .formValidation('addField', 'box[' + bookIndex + '].temperatur', priceValidators);
          })
```

However, as stated I can add inputs dynamically, the problem is getting the values from the dynamically added inputs. I can't seem to find this in the formvalidation.io plugin docs either.

Comment: How do you handle the form submitting? Your inputs are in a form? Do you use ajax?

Comment: Ah, sorry - yes I am using AJAX to submit the form. Just a sec, I will update my question.

Comment: are you changing the name foreach attribute in your template ?

Comment: @bRIMOs Yes. See my updated question. Adding the fields dynamically works like it should, I am just not seeing the values when I submit the form.

Comment: couldyou please `console.log($form.serialize())` to check it's content

Comment: I've added an answer Hope it's gonna help otherwise we'll investigate more !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the matter is in the dataType because you're sending `x-www-form-urlencoded` not a `json` data , so try to change the :

`dataType : "html"` and add  `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` // set by default

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/submit-form',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $form.serialize(),
    dataType : "html",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", 
   ....
});
```

Comment: How can I then access the values? In JSON, I could example use: `data.result` to get the response code from the AJAX submit.